# RPN calculator using push and pop.

Tags: c

I want to design a RPN calculator using push and pop. But I am not getting the right result for e after running the program. It seems that c and d are storing 0 after I use pop() to get the value of a and b from the stack. Any suggestions?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int stack[50];
 int first = 0;
 int main(void){
 int a,b,c,d,e;
 char opr[4];

 printf("Enter 2 numbers \n");
 scanf("%d",&a);
 scanf("%d",&b);
 void push(int x);   // Calling the push function
 int pop();          // Calling the pop function
 push(a);
 push(b);
 printf("Enter the operator \n");
 scanf("%s",&opr[4]);

 switch(opr[4]){
    case '+': c=pop(); d=pop(); e=c+d; break;
    case '-': c=pop(); d=pop(); e=c-d; break;
    case '*': c=pop(); d=pop(); e=c*d; break;
    case '/': c=pop(); d=pop(); e=c/d; break;
    default:  printf("not a valid option");
}
push(e);
printf("%d",e);
printf("%d",stack[50]);
return 0;
}
void push(int x){
    if(first==50){
        printf("The stack is full");
    }else{
        x = stack[first];
        first++;
    }
}
int pop(){
    int y;
    if(first == 0){
        printf("Stack is empty ");
    }else{
        first--;
        y = stack[first];
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&opr[4]);` out of bound --> `scanf("%s", opr);`, `switch(*opr){`

Comment: at `push` : `x = stack[first];
        first++;` --> `stack[first++] = x;`

Comment: I have already tried that BLUEPIXY but it is giving me the same wrong result

Comment: `printf("%d",stack[50]);` out of bound.

Comment: `c=pop(); d=pop();` --> `d=pop(); c=pop();`

Comment: I do not think it's the same. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/BmmoZv)  Is output to expect and  your input?

Comment: I am getting the value of e but I think that it is not being pushed to the stack as stack value is not changing.

Comment: try print stack top like this `printf("\ndebug:%d\n", stack[first-1]);`//e

Comment: Note that these two lines: `void push(int x);   // Calling the push function` and `int pop();          // Calling the pop function` are not calling any functions; they are declaring the `push()` and `pop()` functions.